# Configuring route from source to destination

Tags: networking, routing, solaris

not an expert in Solaris networking so would like to ask your opinions

Say i want to configure packet routing from source 10.126.120.130 (A) to destination 10.214.140.9 (B).

I configured it this way (shown in netstat -rn) on (B)

```
   Destination      Mask            Gateway                 Interface
    =======        =====             =======                 ======
   10.0.0.0         255.0.0.0         10.214.140.1
   10.214.0.0       255.255.128.0     173.20.50.65
   10.214.140.0     255.255.255.192   10.214.140.9           vmnet1
```

where vmnet1 has interface address 10.214.140.9.
May I know if I have configured it properly?
I want packets to go from (A) to (B).

Answer (score 0):

It is correct, assuming 10.214.140.1 has a route to A.

Comment: hi, wouldn't 10.0.0.0 be too wide a network to go for a destination? ie, if I want to go to 10.214.140.9, the OS will use 10.0.0.0 ?

Comment: That would depend on A network. Check the netmask and add a route to it too then.

Comment: hi , i have updated netmask